# Custom console output channels

Tags: c#, output, console-application

I'm working on a problem right now, where I have to read, filter and process console outputs. To parse it correctly is nearly impossible so my question was if it's possible to work with custom output channels. At the moment I only have `Console.Error` and `Console.Out` available. But this is not enough to separate them efficiently.

Example console output:

```
Info text over many lines. It can be everything written in plain text.
Now important messages are coming I have to filter out.

Important Message for C1! It can be everything in plain text.
Important Message for C1! It can be everything in plain text.
Important Message for C1! It can be everything in plain text.

Info text over many lines. It can be everything written in plain text.
Now important messages are coming I have to filter out.

Important Message for C2! It can be everything in plain text.
Important Message for C2! It can be everything in plain text.
Important Message for C2! It can be everything in plain text.
```

Now I want to write the output of C1 like this: `Console.C1.WriteLine("Message 1")`
And for C2: `Console.C2.WriteLine("Message 2")`

The only difference in the console you can see is the color. Maybe i can go on this? If so, it will be good to.

Thank you for your help :D

Comment: Your question is a wee bit unspecific. Could you elaborate on what exactly you want to separate?

Comment: Updated my question. It can be everything. That's the problem. The only difference you can see in console is the color of the text.

Answer (score 0):

You could write the output to files instead of console, so you would have multiple output channels.

Comment: Yes that's a option but writing to disc is not good  in my case because of permissions. It can be that at the moment i want to read the file, some program may access the file like an antivirus who is scanning all files. And data loss will be fatal.  :)

Comment: I data loss will be fatal, why don't you write the log to a database?